# Force Realm notification block to run before proceeding

Tags: ios, swift, realm

The background for this question is that I have an app in which all the tableViews are updated automatically using fine grained Realm notifications. At some point I fetch data from a server to populate a table. In the completion block of the server call, I add the newly fetched object into Realm, triggering a notification that updates the table.

The problem I'm having is that I want to start an animation that uses the newly inserted table cell immediately after adding the object to Realm. Is there a way to force the notification block to run before I proceed to the next line? Here's little pseudo code to try to clarify

```
Network.getDataFromServer() { json in
    let realmObject = Object(json)
    realm.write({
       realm.add(realmObject)
    })

    // Realm notification block needs to complete before getting here
    runAnimation()
}
```

Has anybody encountered a similar problem? I really like using fine grained notifications to manage table views because it's so clean, so I'd really like to find a way to handle scenarios like this one.

Comment: Every time you perform a write operation to the Realm the notifications triggers. The only concern I'm having right now is the efficiency. It is better adding the objects using arrays to the Realm than start and commit a write transaction for every single object you're creating/updating. I'd prefer using the `addObjects()` function just once than running a for loop and the function `add()` on each iteration.

Comment: I realized when I read your comment that my example doesn't match my code very well. I actually have it setup the way you described. One call is made to get all the data for the table, it's added in bulk in one write transaction, and the animation is actually performed on the tableView itself, but does something with tableView.cellAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this in a fully reactive application would be to perform the animation based on the notification coming in. This way, no matter how an object is being added (`getDataFromServer`, a bg thread, or even a different process), your app would react the same way.

This leads to simpler code while being more robust.